# Trying to open a single blog post view from a list of blog posts

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to open a single blog post from a list of the blog post that has created using a recycler adapter. I am not using any adapter on the single blog post activity, what I am working on is a house application where users can post their houses, like and comment on others. What I am trying to do is view a single blog post when that post is selected. So, for this to work, I need to get the document id of that selected blog post so that I can retrieve it from Firestore DB and display it on a single blog post view. The problem is, I am having a hard time to retrieve the document and display it since the document has an autogenerated key.

I had initially created an extendable class that would pass document autogenerated id to the model class I had created for sending documents to the recycler adapter, what I am thinking of is to use the same extendable class so as to pass document id to the single blog post view, how can I implement this?

**Single blog post java:**

```
package com.example.android.houseap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.android.houseap.Listings.HousePost;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

public class SingleHousePost extends AppCompatActivity {

    private  String mPost_key=null;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    private TextView locationTextView;
    private DocumentReference documentRef;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_house_post);

        firebaseFirestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        String house_post_id = String.valueOf(HousePostId.class);  //method 1




        mPost_key=firebaseFirestore.collection("House_Post").document(house_post_id).getId();


        locationTextView=findViewById(R.id.location_city_town);

        String currentUser=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


        DocumentReference docRef = firebaseFirestore.collection("House_Posts").document(mPost_key);
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document.exists()) {
                        String locationHouse=task.getResult().getString("location");

                        locationTextView.setText(locationHouse);

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(SingleHousePost.this, "DATA DOES NOT EXISTS,PLEASE REGISTER", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(SingleHousePost.this, "CANNOT RETRIEVE DATA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            }
        });








    }


}


Extendable class:

        package com.example.android.houseap;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

    import com.google.firebase.firestore.Exclude;

    public class HousePostId {

        @Exclude
        public  String HousePostId;

        public<T extends HousePostId>T withId(@NonNull final String id ){

            this.HousePostId=id;
            return (T) this;
        }

    }
```

[When i press the view house button i should see the contents of this house post only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9inOt.png)

[the contents of the house post selected should be viewed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bLVe.png)

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBfqc.png)

Comment: Please add your database schema and indicate the exact document that you want to get.

Comment: The document i would like to retrieve is the selected document by the user